# Having trouble with sending data from JavaScript to Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am running a simple setup where a string should be sent to my Flask app via Ajax, but I am receiving Error code 400: Bad request.

JavaScript code:

```javascript
headers = {
    'Content-type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json'
}

function send(){
    const line = textbox.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send",
        data: line,
        headers: headers,
    });
}
```

Python code:

```python
@app.route("/send", methods=["POST"])
def print_data():
    data = json.load(request.get_json().get("data"))
    main.FileMan.post_data(str(data))
```

Where the last line is where I call a Python file called main and output the data in a text document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the structure of `textbox.value` is but you need  to stringify  your data before sending it like this:

```
headers = {
    'Content-type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json'
}

function send(){
    const line = textbox.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send",
        data: JSON.stringify(line),
        headers: headers,
    });
}
```

And in your Flask code, you are already using `request.get_json()` to parse the JSON data so you need to remove `json.load()` since you are trying to parse data from a POST request and not from a file. Your Flask code should look like this:

```
@app.route("/send", methods=["POST"])
def print_data():
    data = request.get_json().get("data")
    main.FileMan.post_data(str(data))
}
```